# iphone release vs testing

Tags: iphone, ios, testflight

I'm experiencing problems while releasing testing-builds through testflight. My app is running fine in the simulator and on the device (via xcode) but when testing the app via TestFlight I get different behaviors or sometimes even crashes. 
Everything happens on the same device. iPhone 4 iOS 5.1
One of the problem was images not showing up in iCarousel. Later on after some debugging I realized it was due to a property declared 'weak' instead of 'strong' whose reference was lost after some operations. Problem is... Why does this happen only on ipa via Testflight and does not happen in simulator or device connected?
Have you ever experienced such problem?

Comment: There can be multiple reasons why, you should start by trying to get any crashlog from the devices that the app is crashing on. This should give you some thing to gone on.

Comment: I think you'll have to be more specific what kinds of problems that you're having; what are the different behaviours, when does it crash, what do the crash logs say? It could be many reasons; different devices, different iOS versions, different stored data models, different network connections, different compilation behaviour for test and release configurations etc.

Comment: Can you reproduce the behavior if you run an ad-hoc build from Xcode on your device? I'm not sure this is a TestFlight issue.

Answer (score 0):

Start off by downloading the Crash logs and post the details here.

There are loads of posts in SO on how to get and interpret them. E.g. [Symbolicating iPhone App Crash Reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460892/symbolicating-iphone-app-crash-reports)